# Angular mat-option with multiple values and show only one value when mat-option selected

Tags: angular, mat-select, mat-option

Let's say I have this static object

```
allAccount = [
    { name: 'All Accounts', amount: 140853.47},
    { name: 'Credit Card ',amount: '-455.15' },
];
```

and I have mat-option interface with two values, name and amount.

```
   <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of allAccount" [value]="item.name">
          <div class="flex justify-between">
            <span>
              {{ item.name }}
            </span>
            <span>
              {{ item.amount }}
            </span>
          </div>
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

This is within a mat-select, and once the user selects a choice, It display both item.name and item.amount in concatenated form, but [value]="item.name". How can I only show item.name when the user selects a choice in this case?

Comment: Have you read the docs?

Comment: solved with   <mat-select-trigger> </mat-select-trigger>
Not exactly the same problem, but I got the idea of mat-select-trigger from,

https://stackblitz.com/angular/qkjbojyxebly?file=app%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.html

Comment: No, the exact solution. Duplicates have the same solution. Anyway, the docs are very helpful and it was explained in the docs. Please do a more research before posting

Comment: I just saw that this issue was duplicated, and also this issue is closed, I didn't notice that before
should I delete the question?

Answer (score 1):

**You can do the following:**

```
<h4>mat-select</h4>

<mat-select placeholder="State" required #select>
  <mat-select-trigger> {{ select.value?.name }} </mat-select-trigger>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let val of states" [value]="val">{{val.name }} : {{ val.amount}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

**Please find the Working stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-matselect-c8cdqu?file=app%2Fselect-reset-example.html)**